# Can anyone help me make this script simpler?

Tags: jquery, html, bind, trim

I have a span and a input field, and when the input field is empty, i need it the span to say "Empty". When I input some text in the field, the span will automatically add the letters/numbers to the span. If the inputs value get removed, the span will say "Empty" again.

```
if($.trim($('#input').val()) == ''){
    $('#span').html('Empty');
}
$('#input').bind("change keyup input",function() { 
    $('#span').html($(this).val());
    if($.trim($('#input').val()) == ''){
        $('#span').html('Empty');
    }
});
```

I think this can be implemented in a simpler way and hopefully inside just one function. Can this be possible?

Comment: Didn't downvote but,I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple: set the HTML of the `#span` element with a function, and execute the function both during runtime, and during certain events bound to the `#input` field. I recommend using `.on()` instead of `.bind()`:

```js
// Define function that sets html value
var updateSpan = function() {
  var v = $.trim($(this).val());
  if(v === '') {
    $('#span').html('Empty');
  } else {
    $('#span').html(v);
  }
}

// Execute function at runtime
// We use .call() so that `this` in the function refers to our input
updateSpan.call($('#input')[0]);

// Bind the function as a callback during these events, too
// The element is automatically passed as `this`
$('#input').on('change keyup input', updateSpan);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<span id="span"></span>
```

If you really like confusing code, you can even shorten the `if` statement into this:

```
var updateSpan = function() {
    var v = $.trim($(this).val());
    $('#span').html(v === '' ? 'Empty' : v);
}
```

Comment: Although it takes up much more space than my 4 lines, I think this is easier to grasp. It would be perfect with the condition `$(this).val().trim() == ''`

Comment: If you uglify your JS, everything can be made one line ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input').on("change keyup input",function() { 
    if($.trim($('#input').val()) == ''){
        $('#span').html('Empty');
    } else {
        $('#span').html($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: When you copy and paste using the mouse, there may be change events not involving a keyup.

Comment: @lex82 Alright, let's leave it as is.

Comment: You are missing that the span should be initialized. The event must be triggered once. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only really need keyup in pretty much every case i could think of, of the top of my head.

You could replace .bind by .on and the triggers to just 'keyup'.

After you've created the function, you can call it by triggering one of the triggers while still using the same selector.

Like so;

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){
    text = $(this).val().trim();
    if(text == ''){
        $('#span').html('Empty');
    } else {
        $('#span').html(text);
    }
}).trigger('keyup');
```

Or you could define a function like;

```
$.fn.emptyCheck = function(){
        return (this.val().trim() != '');
}
```

or

```
$.fn.emptyCheck = function(){
    text = this.val().trim();
    if(text == ''){
        $('#selector').html('Empty');
    } else {
        $('#selector').html(text);
}
```

then call it by using

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
      if($(this).emptyCheck()){
          /* your function */ 
      }
});
```

or

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).emptyCheck();
}
```

respectively.

Comment: You forget to update the span when the input is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#input')
    .bind("change keyup input", function() { 
        updateSpan($(this).val());
    })
    .trigger('keyup');

function updateSpan(s) {
    $('#span').html(s.trim() == '' ? 'Empty' : s);
}
```

The final `.keyUp()` makes sure the event is triggered once, so the span is initialized.

You can write this with less code. However, I think this is a good compromise. You can read it in one go and don't have to decrypt complex expressions and there is no redundancy.